# Google Maps V3 Display of Multiple Routes

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, google-maps-api-3

I have the need to split a long route into two parts, one part using motorways and the other not. I have coded two routes

```
var request1 = {
    origin: startlatlng,
    destination: joinLatLng,
    waypoints: [{ location: day1 }, { location: day2 }, { location: day3 }],
    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
};
```

and

```
var request2 = {
    origin: joinLatLng,
    destination: endlatlng,
    avoidHighways: true,
    waypoints: [{ location: day7 }, { location: day8 }, { location: day9 }, { location: day10 }, { location: day11 },
                { location: day12 }, { location: day13}],
    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
};
```

but when I plot each one using

```
directionsService.route(request1, function (response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    }
});
```

and

```
directionsService.route(request2, function (response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    }
});
```

only the second is being displayed. Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I could concatenate the two routes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

directionsDisplay is a DirectionsRenderer object.  It can only render one set of directions at once.  If you create 2 directions renderer objects, such as directionsDisplay1 and directionsDisplay2, each can render one half of the route on the map at the same time

Comment: Thanks for that Danny. Worked a treat. I created one directionsDisplay to render the map and the first route and another to render the other route. I rendered both and defined their map in function init(). I then calculated and displayed each route. Job done.

Comment: @xiecs could you post a example of your code! Thanks in advance!